# Getting null from simple expression

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am using simple in camel for scripting languages.  I just need to set the body to null.

I try this:

```
from("direct:start").setBody().simple("null");
```

and it sets the body to the literal string "null".

If I do this:

```
from("direct:start").setBody().simple("${header.null}");
```

It works but seems a bit clunky.  Is there a simple way to say null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `setBody` directly:

```
from("direct:start").setBody(constant(null));
```

Comment: Can you try with `constant`?

Comment: how to do same that with Spring DSL for camel <2.12? Where ${null} is not implemented yet